# How do I make a sliding search box div like css-tricks has?

Tags: jquery, css

How do I create the same thing as what [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com) has for the SearchBox?

If you click it, it displays one div and animates outwards, and hides the previous div.

I want it to make it cross-browser compatible as well so I am thinking some sort of jQuery solution.

I'm guessing that I'm going to have to onclick of that div, addCss to both divs, i.e. display:none and display block for the one to come out.

If you could put me towards a tutorial or something that would be awesome.

Comment: The implementation is given on the site: http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/4312/css-tricks-search-bar/p1

Comment: Ok, that didn't cover the fact of the jquery code, but i have found something similar which I am going to use http://jsfiddle.net/jPneT/208/